# Sorting tabs by extension in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sorting, tabs, visual-studio-extensions, add-on

Visual Studio allows to sort tabs by alphabetical order, but I would like to sort them by extension. Unfortunately, I don't see this option anywhere.

Is there some some of extension that already does this ?

Ideally, I would even like to sort them by what they actually are, not just by extension, i.e a category for code files that define MVC controllers, another for code files that define MVC models, etc. I suppose this doesn't exist. but is there a simple way to make an extension that would handle this ?

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marcusviar.sort-tabs).

Comment: Thanks. Yes this seems to fulfill my need, but based on what I read in the ratings  and by the author hisself it's kind of buggy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension and with the [Sorter](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/sorter.html) add-in you can order tabs by extension, a part of tab name and other criteria:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That looks like what I'm looking for, but I might attempt creating my own before purchasing one.